# Does Vue have something similar to Svelte's destiny operator?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, svelte

This one-liner in svelte will execute anytime the value of someVar changes.

```
$: console.log({someVar});
```

Svelte calls this a [reactive declaration](https://svelte.dev/examples#reactive-declarations), the code after the `$` label, what Svelte calls the "destiny operator" will be executed whenever any variables referenced within it change.

This is really useful for debugging. Does Vue have something similar?

Comment: I think you can do something like that using a watcher https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers

Answer (score 4):

The most similar API would probably be [`watchEffect()`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/computed-watch-api.html#watcheffect):

```js
watchEffect(() => console.log(someVar.value))
```

*Example:*

```html
<script setup>
import { ref, watchEffect } from 'vue'
const someVar = ref(0)
watchEffect(() => console.log(someVar.value))
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="someVar++">Increment {{ someVar }}</button>
</template>
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-watch-effect?file=src/App.vue)

Comment: That's a lot more code in comparison!

Comment: 1 line compared to 2 lines is not much (import and use). But yes - if you want less code, you should stay with svelte.